# Difference between ELMAH and Global.asax exception handling

Tags: asp.net, elmah, error-logging

I have website and I need to log exceptions globally, cannot understand what is difference between using ELMAH as error logging mechanism or use Application_Error in Global.asax, I think that all will log all exceptions thrown, or I'm missing something about ELMAH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELMAH subscribes to the same [`Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error.aspx) event that `Application_Error` in `Global.asax` is designed to handle. As a result, you will not be at any more disadvantage with `Application_Error` than ELMAH as far as getting notified when an unhanded exception bubbles up to ASP.NET during an HTTP transaction. The difference is that except for very simplistic logging, if your needs ever expand to configurability, filtering errors, generating RSS feeds or building a browsing UI around logged errors then you'll pretty much end up writing the same code in your `Application_Error` as ELMAH gives you. If you plan to use that code in `Application_Error` of other web applications, then it will need to be generalised and rendered pluggable and that, once again, will give you what ELMAH already is.

Comment: does ELMAH works asynchronously or not, if yes it will be great advantage in order not to make performance issues during heavy load time on the server

Comment: The `Error` event has no async support in ASP.NET. Nevertheless, ELMAH has some async support that has been discussed in the [Async Database log](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/elmah/7-QHSwM1WvA/discussion) thread in the [ELMAH Discussion Group](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah).